# Google maps and Places SDK for android not working in release APK

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, maps, google-places-api

I am working on google maps and places SDK for android , its working in debug apk but not working in release mode APK.

Setup steps:

1. Create project on google api console
2. Enabled google maps sdk and android places SDK
3. Took SHA-1 fingerprint from google play console (app signing
   section) and added with package name into my generated key on google
   api console.

Results: Both google map and places sdk work on debug mode but does not work when i create a release APK.

Error: `{statusCode:Error, resolution:null}`

Please suggest what can be issue.

Comment: In case of above solution does not work, please find below link [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69075317/4489222)

Comment: In case of above solution not work, please check the [Solution by Vivek Hande](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69075317/4489222)

Answer (score 1):

Before publishing application into play store you have to follow some step to create release key.

1> First find your key store location.
2> Run this command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
```

3> You will be asked keystore password . Enter the keystore password that you placed while creating a release apk.
4> Copy SHA1 on your terminal Into your Google Console
[image]

[image]

Add your package name and SHA-1
[image]

Comment: Check the link  for other solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69075317/4489222