# Google Maps is not working properly after publishing an app in Google Play store

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play

I developed an Android app which contains Map Activity. Before publishing the application and now the map works properly in the emulator, but the map in the app published in google play does not appear. there is no problem in the position of the device or in the locations where I search, also calculates the distance between the location of the device and the location where I search but the map is completely grayed out.  How can I solve this problem?

Comment: problem is in the development key that you used for production build, as I think

Comment: Did you generate SignAPK for publish? and Have you used SHA1 key anywhere??

Comment: i signed my APK before release. i restricted app with package name and SHA-1 signing-certificate fingerprint on Google Developer Console before release app.

Answer (score 18):

More than 2 days I try to find the answer.
Finally, I found it. What I did was go to `App signing` under `Release management` on your `google play console`
There will be two SHA-1 certificate fingerprint
[image]

Then, go to your Google cloud console under Map API Key.
Put both fingerprints that you obtain from `App signing`
[image]

Voila!!!! a map is rendered :)

Comment: I did the same but don't why google map is still not rendering.

Comment: I have added the debug SHA-1 key and it is working fine with this but not with release SHA-1 key.

Comment: you saved us, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your API key for google maps is [restricted](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup#restrict-key).

> For Android apps, you restrict the key to your app's package name and SHA-1 signing-certificate fingerprint.

You can see key restrictions in [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com)
Check the package name of local builds and published one. Then SHA1 of release and debug certificate. You can download release apk from Google Play console and get SHA1 of cert as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11331951/2893307).

Comment: i restricted app with package name and SHA-1 signing-certificate fingerprint on Google Developer Console before release app.  Do you mean change to none restriction?

Comment: No, please check your restrictions. Compare packageName of release app and SHA1 from key restrictions with real values from published apk.  I've been in same situation. I just made a typo in package name.

Answer (score 0):

I face the issue for the google map, In debug app and release apk before publish on the Google play store Google Map works fine. After publish app in Open testing or production it fails to load.

For this issue there are two possible solution

Solution 1 - Generate restricted release key for the android app, which already explained in above solutions

Solution 2 - In case of above solution not work, then please check the Google Claud  platform (GCP) has activated the billing account.

Once you add the billing account it will work. Happy Coding ;)